# All django databases are deleted

Tags: django

Because I deleted the mysql file by mistake last time, I can't use any database, including django, how to recover all the data tables of django

```
**django==1.9.8**
**python==3.5.2**
```

[image]
This is my profile

Comment: are you talking about the sqlite file? if you deleted it, you can create it again by executing `python manage.py migrate`, but the data is gone unless you recover your file.

Comment: yeah if you want to recover the data from a sqlite file you deleted, well, to bad. Except if you can retrieve it in trash or something. But migrate will generate a new db, but empty.